# How to increase query performance for filling a combobox with 7500 rows in DevExpress?

Tags: sql-server, devexpress

I have a DevEx GridView and inside that I have GridViewDataComboBoxColumn. I need to fill the Combo-box with 7500 rows. I have used the following query in stored procedure sp_select_AllStocks

```
Select StockId,StockName from StockMaster;
```

The below code is used in aspx.cs page to dynamically bind combobox.

```
DataTable dt_fill_StocksCombo = new DataTable();
            dt_fill_StocksCombo = con.select_AllStocks();
            ((GridViewDataComboBoxColumn)gdStocks.Columns["StockName"]).PropertiesComboBox.IncrementalFilteringMode = DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.IncrementalFilteringMode.StartsWith;
            ((GridViewDataComboBoxColumn)gdStocks.Columns["StockName"]).PropertiesComboBox.DropDownStyle = DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.DropDownStyle.DropDown;
            ((GridViewDataComboBoxColumn)gdStocks.Columns["StockName"]).PropertiesComboBox.DataSource = dt_fill_StocksCombo;
            ((GridViewDataComboBoxColumn)gdStocks.Columns["StockName"]).PropertiesComboBox.ValueField = "StockId";
            ((GridViewDataComboBoxColumn)gdStocks.Columns["StockName"]).PropertiesComboBox.TextField = "StockName";
```

The function definition of select_AllStocks() is as follows.

```
public DataTable select_AllStocks()
    {
        Open_Connection();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_select_AllStocks", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter adt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adt.Fill(dt);
        Close_Connection();
        return dt;
    }
```

The above method takes approximately 30 seconds to load combobox with 7500 rows.
Is there a way out to increase the performance?

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox supports fetching records from a data base on demand. The [ASPxComboBox.ItemsRequestedByFilterCondition](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxComboBox_ItemsRequestedByFilterConditiontopic) and [ASPxComboBox.ItemRequestedByValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxComboBox_ItemRequestedByValuetopic) events are used for this. See the [Filtering a Large Data Source](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxComboBox/LargeDataSource.aspx) demo. Here is a solution for how to use this feature in the Grid: [ASPxGridView - Filtering a Large Data Source in a combobox](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T165438)

Answer (score 0):

Public Sub fillCombo(ByVal cbobox As LookUpEdit)
        With cbobox
            cbobox.Properties.Columns.Clear()
            cbobox.Properties.Columns.Add(New LookUpColumnInfo("Code", 10))
            cbobox.Properties.Columns.Add(New LookUpColumnInfo("Name", 20))
            .Properties.Columns.Item(0).Visible = False

```
        ds = INVBl.FillCustomer()
        .Properties.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        .Properties.DisplayMember = "Name"
        .Properties.ValueMember = "Code"
        .Properties.ShowFooter = False
        .Properties.ShowHeader = False
        .Properties.ShowLines = False
    End With
End Sub


Public Sub RfillCombo(ByVal cbobox As Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit, ByVal column As String)
    With cbobox
        cbobox.Properties.Columns.Clear()
        cbobox.Properties.Columns.Add(New LookUpColumnInfo("Code", 10))
        cbobox.Properties.Columns.Add(New LookUpColumnInfo("Name", 20))
        .Properties.Columns.Item(0).Visible = False

        ds = INVBl.FillItem(column)
        .Properties.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        .Properties.DisplayMember = "Name"
        .Properties.ValueMember = "Code"
        .Properties.ShowFooter = False
        .Properties.ShowHeader = False
        .Properties.ShowLines = False
    End With
End Sub
```